# Convert DateTime from English to Spanish in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, date, time, nslocale

Does anybody know how to convert a DateTime from English to Spanish?

E.g convert:

```
December 07, 10:42AM
```

into

```
Diciembre 07, 10:42AM
```

Please help me. How to convert this?

Thanks in advance.

I tried this:

```
 NSLocale *frLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es"] autorelease];
 NSLog(@"%@", [frLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"December 07, 10:42AM"]);
 // Value comes Null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try like below it will help**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd',' hh:mma"];
    NSDate *dateTmp  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"December 07, 10:42AM"]; // getting date from string with english locale
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es"]];
    [dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"AM"]; // default AM symbol for spanish is a.m.
    [dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"PM"]; // default PM symbol for spanish is p.m.
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTmp]; // getting string from date with spanish locale
    NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```

Comment: i have to change address english to spanish, any idea

Comment: means a sting in English to spanish?

Comment: NSString *address = @"Apple store, San francisco" to change spanish

Comment: If that text is static you can use localization string otherwise you need to use google translation but for google translation you need to pay money